# Mailchimp double opt-in and website account confirmation

Tags: php, mysql, mailchimp

I have a web-app where people have to confirm there creation of accounts by clicking a link in the email which moves them from the 'signedup' table to the 'accounts' tables so they can then log in. I want to start sending all my users a newsletter but I don't want to have to send them all a Mailchimp opt-in email so I was wondering if I could use the MailChimp API to combine there MailChimp opt in with my web-app confirmation and try and kill two birds with one stone?

I have tried downloading my accounts table in a CSV and tried importing it, but I would have to do that every week with all the new users and that could take a while and could run into some problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly can!

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

```
// Send data to Mailchimp
require_once('inc/MCAPI.class.php');
$api = new MCAPI('your-api-key');


$result = $api->listSubscribe( 'list-number', $data['email'], $merge_vars, 'html', false );
```

Comment: Thanks man, just had a look at that and a little read of the Google Groups, they work on a trust basis. Will make my life so much easier now :)